# Открывается и сразу закрывается exe файл, который я переделал из .py с помощью Pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

делал по гайду из ютуба, в конце добавил input, чтобы меню не закрывалось, но не помогло :(
в PyCharm код работает, все библиотеки (numpy и pyinstaller) я загрузил.
Когда захожу в папку, и включаю ww.exe появляется чёрная программа, и сразу же закрывается, что делать?

в exe файл я переделывал командой `pyinstaller ww.py` в терминале

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

training_inputs = np.array([[0,0,1],
                            [1,1,1],
                            [1,0,1],
                            [0,1,1]])
training_outputs = np.array([[0,1,1,0]]).T

np.random.seed(1)

synaptic_weights = 2 * np.random.random((3,1)) - 1

print('Случайные инициализирующие веса:')
print(synaptic_weights)
for i in range(20000):
    input_layer = training_inputs
    outputs = sigmoid( np.dot(input_layer, synaptic_weights))

    err = training_outputs - outputs
    adjustments = np.dot(input_layer.T, err * (outputs * (1 - outputs)))
    synaptic_weights += adjustments

print('Веса после обучения:')
print(synaptic_weights)

print ('Результат после обучения:')
print(outputs)

a = input()
```

Comment: Запустить из консоли (cmd или PowerShell) и посмотреть какие ошибки напишет.

Comment: Скорее всего всё-таки с `numpy` проблема. Он не так просто переносится.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот такую команду

```
pyinstaller -D -F -n my_prog.exe -c "ww.py"
```